# how to pass a value to flood light custom variable

Tags: php, google-tag-manager

I need to fire a flood light event snippet from google tag manager, with custom variables pushed. 
But i don't seem to get it right.
for example, i need to set this variable: 'u8': '[page name]'.
In google tag manager i set the snippet with custom variable 'u8' and i gave the value:

`<?php echo $pageName;?>`

The script is fired but the value for this variable remains the php code and not the value that i need.
what am i doing wrong? do i need to insert the script form page? how can i give the variable the value i need?

Comment: GTM does not parse PHP code (php runs on the server, GTM is client side javascript).

Answer (score 0):

If you want an identifier of the page, us the {{Page Path}} variable in Google Tag Manager which will be replaced with the page path.